# Directive to add ng-pattern attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will replace itself with the ng-pattern attribute. The attribute gets applied to the input element but the element basically becomes unusable after that. I can no longer enter characters into the text box.

Here is the plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/F6ZQYzxd8Y04Kz8xQmnZ?p=preview

I think I must be compiling the element incorrectly after the attribute is added.

```
app.directive('passwordPattern', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return{
    compile: function (element, attr){

        element.removeAttr('password-pattern');
        element.attr('ng-pattern', '/^[\\w\\S]{6,12}$/');

        return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                $compile(iElement)(scope);
            }
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

Any thoughts on a solution or why the textbox becomes unusable would be greatly apprecitated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the $compile call in the post link, and not the pre link? Any good reason I don't see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to `priority: 1000`, you need to add `terminal: true`.

The issue is that *without* `terminal: true`, the `input` directive gets compiled twice, and 2 sets of change listeners are getting added, which throws the `ngModel` directive logic off a bit.

The first compile Angular performs doesn't see the `ng-pattern`, so the input directive doesn't add the `validateRegex` parser to its list of parsers.  However, the second compile (via your `$compile(iElement, scope)`) sees the `ng-pattern` and *does* [add](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L992) the `validateRegex` parser.

When you type, say `3`, into the input box, the [first change listener is called](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L901) and sees the number `3`.  Since no `ng-pattern` was applied (which would've added the `validateRegex $parser`), no `$parsers` exist and the model is updated with `3` immediately.

However, when the second change listener is called, it sees the `ng-pattern` and calls `validateRegex`, which [calls](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L859) `ngModel.$setValidity('pattern', false)` and [returns](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L860) `undefined` (because the model should never be set to an invalid value).  Here's the kicker - inside the `ngModel` directive, since the previous `$viewValue` of `3` and new `value` of `undefined` are [out of sync](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1854), Angular calls the input directive's `$render` function, which [updates the input](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L983) to be empty.  Thus when you type `3` (or anything) into the input box, it's immediately removed and appears to be broken.

A high `priority` (like `1000`) and `terminal: true` will prevent the input directive (and most likely other directives unless you have one that's `priority: 1001+`) from being compiled the first time.  This is great because you *want* the input directive to take into account ng-pattern - not without it in place.  You don't want multiple sets of change listeners added to the same element or it may (and will) cause strange side-effects.

Comment: adding terminal resolved the problem. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to override the `pattern` property of the `$validators` object in `ngModel` controller.

You can see an example of a validator function in [ngModelController docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Here's an example in a directive:

```
angular.module('mymodule')
    .directive('mydirective', MyDirective);

function MyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$validators["pattern"] = validatePattern;

            function validatePattern(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                return /[0-9]+/.test(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify the above example to receive the pattern from the outside scope and change the validation function using a `scope.$watch` on the pattern.